# Download pdf without opening in browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, render

I want to download pdf file directly without viewing, i have tries following things till now but nothing is helping.

```
1- window.open("https://s3-link1.pdf", 'Download');

2- <a href="https://s3-link1.pdf" download>Link</a>
```

Link - https://s3-link1.pdf

Assume my domain is *https://www.somedomain.com*

I somewhere read we can't download cross-origin files. content-disposition header is required to be passed from backend. I am puzzled here. Another csv file of cross-origin is being downloaded easily.

https://s3-link2.csv

I just need to download pdf file using javascript. Please guide me.

Comment: Not sure about the context. You can right click the link and "Save as..." from context menu.

Comment: Do you want a script that can copy-paste into browser console and batch download links from the page you're currently viewing?

Comment: I think what she means as long as it hits on url. File should automatically downloaded

Answer (score 4):

Try with fetch.

```
fetch("https://s3-link1.pdf", {
    method: 'GET'
}).then(resp => resp.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "name"; // the filename you want
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
with jQuery you can try this:

```
$.get("https://s3-link1.pdf", function (result)
{
    var blob = new Blob([result]);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "myFileName.pdf";
    link.click();
});
```

Option 2:
The `download` attribute works in all modern browsers, including MS Edge, but not Internet Explorer.

In the latest versions of Chrome, you cannot download cross-origin files (they have to be hosted on the same domain).

```
<a href="https://s3-link1.pdf" download>Download PDF</a>
```

Find more about it here on this blog: https://actualwizard.com/html-force-download-file

Comment: Option 2: cross-origin link is working using window.open(), csv gets downloaded easily but not if it's a pdf. why so?
https://supply-guide.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/CAMPAIGN_PROPERTIES_LIST_1597153535597.csv

Comment: it's not downloading, it's following the URL, and for that file type 'csv' the browser does the default action of saving the file, whereas with 'pdf', the default action is to open the file in the browser. When using the 'download' attribute, you might encounter the CORS problem.