# How to download PDF automatically on click instead of opening it in new tab using js?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have an input URL with which I want to download pdf file directly without viewing it in a new tab or on the same tab, I have tried following things till now but nothing is helping. Frist tried with this

```
http.success(function (data) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = data.results[0].value.url;
  link.download = data.results[0].value.url.substr(data.results[0].value.url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  link.click();
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  setTimeout(function () {
  document.body.removeChild(link);
     }, 100);
}.bind(this));
```

This script is not downloading the file. It opens the file in the same tab.
Have tried all the answers in these previously answered questions. But nothing worked for me.
[How can I download a pdf from a url using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963990/how-can-i-download-a-pdf-from-a-url-using-javascript)
[How to download PDF automatically using js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691525/how-to-download-pdf-automatically-using-js)
[Download pdf without opening in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723141/download-pdf-without-opening-in-browser)

Then I tried with this **Blob**. Added the blob to my script and then tried again.

```
http.success(function (data) {
  var blob=new Blob([data.results[0].value.url],{ type: "application/pdf" });
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = data.results[0].value.url.substr(data.results[0].value.url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  link.click();
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  setTimeout(function () {
  document.body.removeChild(link);
     }, 100);
}.bind(this));
```

But this time it downloads the file. But can't able to open it. The downloaded file is corrupted.
Have tried the answers in these questions. But nothing worked for me.
[PDF is corrupted after reconstructing it using URL.createObjectURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232820/pdf-is-corrupted-after-reconstructing-it-using-url-createobjecturl)
[Problem downloading a PDF blob in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817280/problem-downloading-a-pdf-blob-in-javascript)
[Blob from buffer returns corrupted pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798591/blob-from-buffer-returns-corrupted-pdf)

please let me know if there are any other ways to download the pdf file directly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What is stored in data.results[0].value.url?

Is it just a link to the PDF? If that's the case you will need to fetch the pdf document first.

Try this

```
http.success(function (data) {
  fetch(data.results[0].value.url)
    .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then((pdfFile) => {
      const blob = new Blob([pdfFile], { type: "application/pdf" });

      const anchor = document.createElement("a");

      anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      anchor.download = "SOME FILENAME.PDF";
      // some browser needs the anchor to be in the doc
      document.body.append(anchor);
      anchor.click();
      anchor.remove();
      // in case the Blob uses a lot of memory
      window.addEventListener(
        "focus",
        () => {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(anchor.href);
        },
        {
          once: true,
        }
      )
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But this also gave me the corrupted file. below given answer worked for my case.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend trying the simplest example.

```js
const pdfLink = data.results[0].value.url

const download = (url) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');

    link.setAttribute('download', 'fileName.pdf');
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.click();
}

downloadBlob = (blob) => download(URL.createObjectURL(blob))

fetch(pdfLink)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(downloadBlob)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This script worked for my case.

Comment: @Rajasirpi accept this answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I share you a piece of code using MUI + JS

```
<IconButton variant="contained"
                      sx={{
                        fontSize: '1rem',
                        fontWeight: 'normal',
                        color:'silver',
                      }}
                      component='label'
                      size={'small'}
                      onClick={() => {
                        const url = 'https:.....'
                        fetch(url)
                          .then((res) => { return res.blob(); })
                          .then((data) => {
                            const a = document.createElement("a")
                            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data)
                            a.download = formValues[id]
                            a.click()
                          });
                      }}>
    <VisibilityIcon />
</IconButton>
```